# Implement Virtual Memory with Memory Mapped Files

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe, memory-mapped-files, virtual-memory

Is it possible to wrap up memory mapped files something like this?

```
TVirtualMemoryManager = class
public
  function  AllocMem (Size : Integer) : Pointer;
  procedure FreeMem (Ptr : Pointer);
end;
```

Since the memory mapped file API functions all take offsets I don't know how to manage the free areas in the memory mapped files. My only idea is to implement some kind of basic memory management (mainting free lists for different block sizes) but I don' t know how efficient this will be.

**EDIT**: What I **really** want (as David made clear to me) is this:

```
IVirtualMemory = interface
  function  ReadMem (Addr : Int64) : TBytes;
  function  AllocateMem (Data : TBytes) : Int64;
  procedure FreeMem (Addr : Int64);
end;
```

I need to store continous blocks of bytes (each relatively small) in virtual memory and be able to read them back into memory using a 64-bit adress. Most of the time access is read-only. If a write is necessary I would just use `FreeMem` followed by `AllocMem` since the size will be different anyway.

I want a wrapper for a memory mapped file with this interface. Internally it has a handle to a memory mapped files and uses `MapViewOfFile` on each `ReadMem` request. The `Addr` 64-bit integers are just offsets into the memory mapped file. The open question is how to assign those adresses - I currently keep a list of free blocks that I maintain.

Comment: What do you mean by "virtual memory"? The system already does that for you.

Comment: I want to circumvent the 2/3/4 GB memory limit and want the virtual memory backed by a file (the page file in this case).

Comment: In that case you need a different interface than this. You need an interface that gets you past the address space limit and this doesn't.

Comment: Can you propose an interface then? I know that you do some data-intensive stuff at work, so maybe you have experiences with that?

Comment: @MarcusAdams Have a look at the title of my question. That was the whole idea :) I just got the interface wrong. See my edit.

Comment: The interface is getting closer. Sadly that's the easy bit. Writing your own memory manager backed by memory mapped files sounds like a big job to do well.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks. It might work in my case because there are actually very few `FreeMem` calls, so a simple implementation might just work okay. Are there alternatives with similar possibilities?

Comment: @Smasher If there are very few FreeMems then just ignore them and view the memory as being infinite! That turns it from a hard job into a trivial one.

Comment: @David: you mean just keep track of a `FMaxAddr` and then do `Addr := FMaxAddr; FMaxAddr := FMaxAddr + Length (Data)`? That's a good idea.

Comment: @Smasher Yes, something like that should get it done.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your proposal that "*Internally it has a handle to a memory mapped files and uses MapViewOfFile on each ReadMem request*" will be just a waste of CPU resource, IMHO.
2. It is worth saying that your `GetMem / FreeMem` requirement won't be able to break the 3/4 GB barrier. Since all allocated memory will be mapped into memory until a call to `FreeMem`, you'll be short of memory space, just as with the regular Delphi memory manager. The best you can do is to rely of `FastMM4`, and change your program to reduce its memory use.
3. IMHO you'll have to change/update your specification. For instance, your "updated" question sounds just like a regular storage problem.

What you want is to be able to allocate more than 3/4 GB of data for your application. You have a working implementation of such a feature in our [SynBigTable](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=Downloads) open source unit. This is a fast and light  [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) solution in pure Delphi.

It is able to create a file of any size (only 64 bit limited), then will map the content of each record into memory, on request. It will use a memory mapping of the file, if possible.  You can implement your interface very directly with `TSynBigTable` methods: `ReadMem=Get, AllocMem=Add, FreeMem=Delete`. The IDs will be your `pointer`-like values, and `RawByteString` will be used instead of `TBytes`.

You can access any block of data using an integer ID, or a string ID, or even use a sophisticated field layout (inside the record, or as in-memory metadata - including indexes and fast search).

Or rely on a regular embedded SQL database. For instance, [SQLite3](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/07/22/SynDBSQLite3%3A-SQLite3-direct-access) is very good at handling BLOB fields, and is able to store huge amount of data. With a simple in-memory caching mechanism for most used records, it could be a powerful solution.

Comment: The idea would presumably be to unmap memory when it is no longer needed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's why even the new ReadMem method interface in the question is not sufficient. Using a storage library will rely on allocating the memory on request. As my first point says, mapping and unmapping have a cost - the APIs were not designed meant for small blocks of memory - for instance the [minimum x86 paging is 4 KB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)), and every memory map will require additional memory (Windows handle, additional memory structures...).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The problem with this question is that the technical design is already fixed - and IMHO is wrong. Memory mapping are not to be used as the OP proposed. It won't be efficient. Therefore, I suggested to go into another directions to solve the original software need: handling a huge number of memory blocks, without the 3/4 GB memory limitation of a 32 bit program. This needs a regular storage engine (either NoSQL or SQL). It is sometimes a good idea and time saving to rely on existing libraries.

Comment: Of course memory will be unmapped after reading, so `ReadMem` is sufficient. The higher-level idea is to have object references that know how to serialize and swap themselves when reference count drops to zero. I have a huge in-memory object hierarchy to handle and this is just an idea I am evaluating. So thanks for the input on this. Using a table would mean basically giving up on my object hiearchy which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @Smasher You can have an object hierarchy stored in a table, using one  ID per object. Just create a linked list of objects, using the IDs to nest them. You can see an ID just like a pointer. The interest of NoSQL engines like our SynBigTable is that the record size is not fixed. It will use a `RawByteString`, just like a `TBytes` of your interface (in this, you are right, `ReadMem` will be sufficient). You can implement your interface very directly with TSynBigTable methods: ReadMem=Get, AllocMem=Add, FreeMem=Delete.

Comment: +1 Thanks again for the helpful discussion. I'll look into SynBigTable. I'll also add a comment after evaluating the performance of mapping small memory blocks.